# If statement in Excel 2013 - if this date is 1 or more days past this date then

Tags: date, comparison

I'm trying to create a formula to compare the amount of days between two dates.  Basically if one date (column D) is within 1 day of the previous date (column C), then "Yes" (in column E) if greater than 1 day then "No" (in Column E)

Answer (score 1):

Dates (that do not include times) in Excel are basically numbers of days. 
So, to get the number of days between two dates, just subtract. 
If you want to check whether the two dates are the same ±1, use

```
=IF(ABS(D1-C1)<=1, "Yes", "No")
```

If you want to check only in one direction, leave out the `ABS(…)`.

If the above doesn’t work, try typing

```
=D1-C1
```

into a cell (any cell *other than* `C1` or `D1`;
could be `E1`; could be `Z1`). 
If that displays a number like 3
(for your example of `D1` = 8/28/2017 and `C1` = 8/25/2017), try

```
=ABS(D1-C1)
```

and in any event edit your question to tell us what happens. 
(Don’t use comments.) 
A screenshot may be useful.

If `D1-C1` works but `ABS(D1-C1)`,
and your system is configured for a non-English language,
you may need to figure out Excel’s translation for `ABS` (absolute value)
in your language.

Other experiments that may be enlightening:

- `=C1`
- `=C1-7`
- `=D1`
- `=D1-7`

Comment: I tried that and it did not work.  For example, the dates are in this format: 8/28/2017.  So for the first line, I need to compare how many days are between 8/28/2017(Column D) and 8/25/2017(Column C).

Comment: @hthomas What results did you get that makes you think Scott's formula doesn't work?  Are columns C and D formatted as dates or text?

Comment: there were no results, just an error that popped up in the formula.  I wrote it just like he said.  Columns C and D are formatted as Short Date